# Dayan speed cube 3x3x3 all corners twisted?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I have solved 3x3x3 cubes as well as 4x4x4, 5x5x5, 6x6x6, 7x7x7 and the megaminx from some time now but this one is really bugging me. I won't consider my self an expert but I have not experienced anything like this before.
One of my students messed around with the cube and suddenly the corners won't orient correctly. I tried solving it several times but without being able to solve the corners.
My first thought was that she must have twisted the corners too quickly but it does not help when I twist them back either way.
I am really stuck. I do hope someone can help. I have taken pictures of the cube from all sides.
As you can see all corners are twisted wrong.
Cheers from Peter[image: pic 1][image: new solve]

Comment: At first when she gave it back to me it looked completely solved except the middle layer was another colour. I tried to align the layers again but could not fix it. After that I just tried to solve it but now it does not look like that first state again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but yes I have tried that several times with the same result. I event tried starting with different starting colour (i use beginner method with the cross)

Comment: The closest I can get is the whole cube solved except the top layer. I place the edge pieces, corner pieces and the top layer is the correct colour on top. I then begin to orientate the corners correctly. When I do that the cube ends up nearly solved but some odd pices completely wrong. I cannot get to the same stage as the pictures anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s very unsolvable. The centers are not movable, and there is no possible way to orient the corner piece in the first picture so that it would align with the centers.

Most likely, the caps on the center pieces have been swapped.

My 3D visualization isn’t perfect, but I think swapping two opposing centers (no matter which) might fix this.

This is based on the observation that each corner has a possible spot with correct neighboring center colors, but two of the colors are always the wrong way, and you would need a mirror image of the corner piece to fit. (Even taking apart the cube wouldn’t help). The most likely reason is that the centers’ order has been mirrored, which happens when any two opposing centers are swapped.

Comment: That is my opinion as well but she did not take the pieces out. She was only turning and twisting. I have never experienced a 3x3x3 cube that was unsolvable. I was sitting near her and the cube was not taken apart.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will try that. Thanks

Comment: I think you are on to something because I tried solving the cube as if white was yellow etc. I managed to solve it completely except the White and yellow Center was wrong. It looks like this (see new picture in my original post)

Comment: ok, that completely proves that two opposing centers have been swapped.

Comment: I have not switched the Center pieces because I need to take out several pieces to do that. But it is strange that I can solve the whole cube now but the two centres are wrong. I had some trouble with the pictures but now there is a picture of this

Comment: But how did she do that? She is only 8. And the cube was not in pieces. Anyway I will try exchange the two Center pieces later on

Comment: Just a guess, of course, but maybe she dropped the cube, two center caps popped out, and she put them back in the wrong order? (I don’t have that particular kind of cube, but the ones I have do have center caps that pop out rather easily, especially if you have opened them before, e.g. for access to the screws)

Comment: Yes maybe. This type of cube is not that great. The pieces pop out easily. I have just exchanged the Center pieces. You were right. The surface comes off easily. Great. Now it works again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No need to thank, an upvote and the tick to mark the solution as correct will do just fine. :-)